# How draw line between point using achart engine android

Tags: android, line, draw, achartengine

Here i attach screen shot where i got point but not getting draw line between them because there is i need skip month value where null data so please suggest where which month have MathHelper.NULL_VALUE that skip and draw line with next value.

[image: Line chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this library and make custom change so I got result.com.jjoe64.graphview.LineGraphView
[check this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.jjoe64.graphview.LineGraphView)